# How to quickly tell this matrix is not rank 1?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rank-1-matrices

Is it possible to quickly evaluate the following matrix is rank 1 or not?
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\
    -1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\
    -1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\
    -1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
    -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similarly, if a matrix is of rank $1$, then its column/row space has dimension $1$, namely if you fix a column/row, all other columns/rows are scalar multiples of the fixed one.

Apparently, your new matrix is also not of rank $1$.

Answer (score 4):

If a matrix is rank $1$, then each of its $2\times 2$ submatrices has zero determinant. However, the top left $2\times 2$ submatrix of your matrix has determinant $-1$. So, your matrix is not rank $1$.

Comment: sorry, I mistakenly wrote the diagonal to be zero, and in fact it is 1. And, why "If a matrix is rank 1, then each of its 2×2 submatrices has zero determinant"? Could you provide some references?

Comment: @M.K It is about principal minors. Check this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)#Other_applications